# Can you somewhere on you phone view a list of all applications and who made them?

Tags: applications, 2.2-froyo

In another question I was asked which Calendar application I was running on my Android 2.2 Samsung Galaxy S phone.

I found the *Applications  - Manage applications* setting, but that shows only the version if you click on an appication, and this doesn't show which company created it.

Is there a standard application which gives me this info: e.g. **name of application**,  **version nr** and **manufacturer** ?

Or if no standard application is available, any recommendations ?

It seems to me that a lot of questions in this forum should benefit of people specifying in their question which version of which program they are asking questions about, no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For applications installed from Market, you can go to `Market > Downloads` for application name and developer info; however built-in applications (e.g. Phone, Calendar, other applications installed by default) often are not shown in Market list (neither will they show in Manage Application either).